# Java changes date to next day when recieving it from API with time

Tags: java, json, date, formatter

I'm calling an API (rest) from java code which will return an object containing a date as a response.

I'm receiving the API response in an object containing a `java.util.Date` variable ( can't change it ).

The problem is that the API returns the date as `"2000-01-01T23:00:00.000+00:00"`
but when Java deserializes it, I get `"2000-01-02T00:00:00.000+00:00"`.

So it's kind of rounding it to the next day , it may be a timezone issue (I don't think so ).
I'm not using any formatter on the date.

I tried to use `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")`

Same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: That response is an ISO Timestamp, not a "java.util.date variable". When you're using Date, then the issue is your code. Date doesn't handle timezones and is outdated anyway. Use java.time classes (e.g. OffsetDateTime) instead.

Comment: thank you for your answer , the thing is I can't change the object that I'm using to recieve the response from the api

Comment: You expect us to tell you what goes wrong in your Java code without you having shown us any Java code? I consider that unlikely to happen.

Comment: there's nothing to show , I"m using a simple RestTemplate to call a rest API

Comment: >  it may be a timezone issue (Idon't think so ) 
Likely is just that

Comment: @g00se I certainly agree that a time zone issue is heavily suspected, on the other hand cannot explain in itself what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the time zone, you send the time 23:00:00, by increasing the respective time by the time zone, it reaches the day.